# Trabajo práctico en c

Tags: c

Hola ¿qué tal? estoy haciendo un trabajo práctico en c.
Antes que me maten, quiero mencionar que obviamente debe tener errores de novato.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX_STRLEN 256


//0
void funcionlarechingada(int nticket, int destino, int tipodebutaca, int acumpasajesvendidos, bool estadoventa, int destinoboleto, int butacastipo, 
int acumboletospullman, int contboletosmdp, int contboletosnch, int contboletosbahia, int pasajesvendidos);
{

printf("ingrese un numero de ticket o ticket = 0 para volver al menu anterior\n");
    scanf("%i",nticket);
    system("cls");
        if (nticket!=0) {
            while (destino!=1 && destino!=2 && destino!=3) {
                printf("seleccione 1 para viajes a Mar del Plata\n");
                printf("seleccione 2 para viajes a necochea\n");
                printf("seleccione 3 para viajes a bahia blanca\n");
                scanf("%i",destino);
                system("cls");}
                
            while (tipodebutaca!=1 && tipodebutaca!=2) {
                printf("ingrese tipo de viaje\n");
                printf("seleccione 1 para pullman\n");
                printf("seleccione 2 para turista\n");
                scanf("%i", tipodebutaca);
                system("cls");}
                
    acumpasajesvendidos = acumpasajesvendidos+1;
    estadoventa = true;
    destinoboleto[destino] = destinoboleto[destino]+1;
    butacastipo[tipodebutaca] = butacastipo[tipodebutaca]+1;
    if (destino==2 && tipodebutaca==1) {
        acumboletocochepullman = acumboletocochepullman+1;}
        switch (destino) {
                        case 1:
                            contboletosmdp = contboletosmdp+1;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            contboletosnch = contboletosnch+1;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            contboletosbahia = contboletosbahia+1;
                            break;
                        }
                        switch (tipodebutaca) {
                        case 1:
                            pasajesvendidos[0] = pasajesvendidos[0]+1;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            pasajesvendidos[1] = pasajesvendidos[1]+1;
                            break;
                        }
                        destino = 0;
                        tipodebutaca = 0;
                        printf("......\n");
                        printf(".....\n");
                        printf("le deseamos un buen viaje\n");
                        printf("....\n");
                        printf(".....\n");
                    }
};







//1
void imprimirTotalPasajesVendidos(bool estadoventa, int acumpasajesvendidos);

//2

void imprimirPromedioPasajesVendidos(bool estadoventa, float promvalboletovendido, float turistaprecio, float pullmanprecio, int pasajesvendidos[], int acumpasajesvendidos)
{
if (estadoventa!=true) {
                        printf("********************************\n");
                        printf("POR FAVOR CARGUE DATOS DEL BOLETO\n");
                        printf("********************************\n");
                    } else {
                        promvalboletovendido = promvalboletovendido+(pasajesvendidos[0]*pullmanprecio);
                        promvalboletovendido = promvalboletovendido+(pasajesvendidos[1]*turistaprecio);
                        promvalboletovendido = promvalboletovendido/acumpasajesvendidos;
                        printf("el promedio de pasajes vendidos es%f\n",promvalboletovendido);
                    }
                    
                    };

int main() {
    /* defino mis variables de numeros enteros */
    int tipodebutaca;
    int menu;
    int nticket;
    int acumboletocochepullman;
    int acumbutacapullman;
    int acumbutacaturista;
    int acumpasajesvendidos;
    int butacassoliciatadasturistas;
    int butacassolicitadaspullman;
    int butacassolicitadasturista;
    int cantpasajes;
    int contboletosbahia;
    int contboletosmdp;
    int contboletosnch;
    int contboletosvendidos;
    int continiciosesion;
    int destino;

    /* defino msi variables de numeros Reales */
    float promvalboletovendido;
    float pullmanprecio;
    float turistaprecio;

    /* defino msi variables logicas */
    bool estadomenu;
    bool estadoventa;
    bool login;
    
    /* defino msi variables de caracteres */
    char pass[MAX_STRLEN];
    char *passdb;
    char user[MAX_STRLEN];
    char *userdb;
    
    /* defino mis variables de vectores */
    int pasajesvendidos[2];
    int destinoboleto[4];
    int butacastipo[3];


    
    
    /* inicializo mis variables logicas */  
    estadoventa = false;
    estadomenu = true;
    login = false;
    
    /* inicializo mis variables de caracter */
    userdb = "jds";
    passdb = "jds";
    
    /* inicializo mis variables de numero Enteros */
    nticket = 33;
    menu = 10;
    destino = 33;
    tipodebutaca = 33;
    continiciosesion = 0;
    cantpasajes = 0;
    acumpasajesvendidos = 0;
    acumboletocochepullman = 0;
    acumbutacapullman = 0;
    acumbutacaturista = 0;
    butacassolicitadasturista = 0;
    butacassolicitadaspullman = 0;
    
    /* inicializo mis variables de numero reales */
    turistaprecio = 2500.00;
    pullmanprecio = 4000.00;
    promvalboletovendido = 0.00;
    
    do {
        printf("usuario\n");
        scanf("%s",user);
        printf("pass\n");
        scanf("%s",pass);
        if (strcmp(user,userdb)==0 && strcmp(pass,passdb)==0) {
            login = true;
            system("cls");
            
        } else {
            system("cls");
            printf("error de login,intente de nuevo \n");
            continiciosesion = continiciosesion+1;
        }
    } while (!(login!=false || continiciosesion==3));
    
    if (login==true) {
        while (estadomenu==true) {
            printf("por favor ingrese 0 para ingresar datos\n");
            printf("por favor ingrese 1 para saber cantidad de boletos vendidos\n");
            printf("ingrese 2 para obtener el promedio del valor del boleto vendido en dinero\n");
            printf("ingrese 3 para saber cuantos boletos se vendieron a necochea en pullman\n");
            printf("ingrese 4 para saber cual destino es el mas solicitado en total\n");
            printf("ingrese 5 para saber cual clase en total es al menos solicitada\n");
            printf("ingrese 10 para salir\n");
            scanf("%i",&menu);
            system("cls");
            if (menu>-1 && menu<11) {
                switch (menu) {
                case 0:

                
                /*
                    printf("ingrese un numero de ticket o ticket = 0 para volver al menu anterior\n");
                    scanf("%i",&nticket);
                    system("cls");
                    if (nticket!=0) {
                        while (destino!=1 && destino!=2 && destino!=3) {
                            printf("seleccione 1 para viajes a Mar del Plata\n");
                            printf("seleccione 2 para viajes a necochea\n");
                            printf("seleccione 3 para viajes a bahia blanca\n");
                            scanf("%i",&destino);
                            system("cls");
                        }
                        while (tipodebutaca!=1 && tipodebutaca!=2) {
                            printf("ingrese tipo de viaje\n");
                            printf("seleccione 1 para pullman\n");
                            printf("seleccione 2 para turista\n");
                            scanf("%i",&tipodebutaca);
                            system("cls");
                        }
                        acumpasajesvendidos = acumpasajesvendidos+1;
                        estadoventa = true;
                        destinoboleto[destino] = destinoboleto[destino]+1;
                        butacastipo[tipodebutaca] = butacastipo[tipodebutaca]+1;
                        if (destino==2 && tipodebutaca==1) {
                            acumboletocochepullman = acumboletocochepullman+1;
                        }
                        switch (destino) {
                        case 1:
                            contboletosmdp = contboletosmdp+1;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            contboletosnch = contboletosnch+1;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            contboletosbahia = contboletosbahia+1;
                            break;
                        }
                        switch (tipodebutaca) {
                        case 1:
                            pasajesvendidos[0] = pasajesvendidos[0]+1;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            pasajesvendidos[1] = pasajesvendidos[1]+1;
                            break;
                        }
                        destino = 0;
                        tipodebutaca = 0;
                        printf("......\n");
                        printf(".....\n");
                        printf("le deseamos un buen viaje\n");
                        printf("....\n");
                        printf(".....\n");
                    }*/
                    break;
                case 1:
                    imprimirTotalPasajesVendidos(estadoventa, acumpasajesvendidos);
                    break;
                case 2:
                imprimirPromedioPasajesVendidos(estadoventa, promvalboletovendido, turistaprecio, pullmanprecio, pasajesvendidos, acumpasajesvendidos);
                /*  if (estadoventa!=true) {
                        printf("********************************\n");
                        printf("POR FAVOR CARGUE DATOS DEL BOLETO\n");
                        printf("********************************\n");
                    } else {
                        promvalboletovendido = promvalboletovendido+(pasajesvendidos[0]*pullmanprecio);
                        promvalboletovendido = promvalboletovendido+(pasajesvendidos[1]*turistaprecio);
                        promvalboletovendido = promvalboletovendido/acumpasajesvendidos;
                        printf("el promedio de pasajes vendidos es%f\n",promvalboletovendido);
                    }*/
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (estadoventa!=true) {
                        printf("********************************\n");
                        printf("POR FAVOR CARGUE DATOS DEL BOLETO\n");
                        printf("********************************\n");
                    } else {
                        if(acumboletocochepullman < 1)
                            {
                            printf("no se han vendido boletos en coche pullman a necochea");
                            }
                        else
                            {
                            printf("la cantidad de boletos vendidos a necochea en la clase pullman es\n");
                            printf("%f\n",acumboletocochepullman);  
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    if (estadoventa!=true) {
                        printf("********************************\n");
                        printf("POR FAVOR CARGUE DATOS DEL BOLETO\n");
                        printf("********************************\n");
                    } else {
                        if (contboletosmdp>contboletosnch && contboletosmdp>contboletosbahia) {
                            printf("los boletos mas vendidos son los de mar del plata\n");
                        }
                        if (contboletosnch>contboletosmdp && contboletosnch>contboletosbahia) {
                            printf("los boletos mas vendidos son los de necochea\n");
                        }
                        if (contboletosbahia>contboletosmdp && contboletosbahia>contboletosmdp) {
                            printf("los boletos mas vendidos son los de Bahia Blanca\n");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 5:
                    if (estadoventa!=true) {
                        printf("********************************\n");
                        printf("POR FAVOR CARGUE DATOS DEL BOLETO\n");
                        printf("********************************\n");
                    } else {
                        
                        if (pasajesvendidos[0]>pasajesvendidos[1]) {
                            printf("las butacas pullman son las menos solicitadas\n");
                        } else {
                            printf("las butacas turistas son las menos solicitadas\n");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 10:
                    estadomenu = false;
                    printf("adios\n");
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                printf("las opciones ingresadas no son validas\n");
            }
        }
    } else {
        printf("excedio los limites de inicio de sesion\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

/*funciones */
/*funciones */
/*funciones */

void imprimirTotalPasajesVendidos(bool estadoventa, int acumpasajesvendidos)
{
if (estadoventa!=true) {
    printf("********************************\n");
    printf("POR FAVOR CARGUE DATOS DEL BOLETO\n");
    printf("********************************\n");
        } else {
            printf("la cantidad de pasajes vendidos es%i\n",acumpasajesvendidos);
            }   
};
```

Me piden que yo cargue los datos usando una funcion, la cual es llamada cuando "menu" es 0.

Funciona, sin la funcion, cuando yo lo hago desde dentro de la funcion, funciona pero no modifica las variables.
¿Por qué? ¿Es porque tengo que sacar las variables por return? ¿Las tengo que llamar desde un puntero? ¿La funcion debe ser global?

La funcion se llama "funcionlarechingada"

Gracias

Comment: No pienso mirarme 311 líneas de código. ¿Cuál es el problema y dónde está?

Answer (score 2):

> cuando yo lo ahgo desde dentro de la funcion, funciona pero no modifica las variables ¿por qué?

Las variables declaradas como parámetros de una función son **una copia** de las variables originales.

Imagina que clonas una mosca y, posteriormente, pintas al clon de rojo... ¿qué le pasa a la mosca original? pues absolutamente nada... lo mismo sucede con las variables de un programa.

La razón de este comportamiento es que cada variable tiene su propia dirección de memoria o su propio registro del sistema y, en consecuencia, acaban siendo variables totalmente independientes unas de otras

> ¿es porque tengo que sacar las variables por return?

Con la instrucción `return` únicamente puedes devolver un valor (o una estructura de datos).

Las estructuras sirven para agrupar variables que están relacionadas entre ellas, como por ejemplo los datos personales de un usuario o las especificaciones de un vehículo... o los datos de un **billete de avión**

```
enum Destino
{
  DESTINO_NINGUNO,
  DESTINO_MAR_DE_PLATA,
  DESTINO_NECOCHEA,
  DESTINO_BAHIA_BLANCA
};

enum TipoButaca
{
  BUTACA_NINGUNA,
  BUTACA_PULLMAN,
  BUTACA_TURISTA
};

struct billete
{
  int nticket;
  Destino destino;
  TipoButaca tipoDeButaca;
  // ...
};
```

Agrupar elementos comunes en una estructura te permite mantener todos esos datos agrupados bajo un mismo paraguas. Además, puedes hacer un `return` de una estructura, luego podría ser una solución perfectamente aplicable a tu problema:

```
struct billete nuevo_billete()
{
  struct billete billete;

  billete.nticket = 123;
  billete.destino = DESTINO_NECOCHEA;
  billete.tipoDeButaca = BUTACA_TURISTA;

  return billete;
}

int main()
{
  struct billete billete = nuevo_billete();

  printf("billete no: %d\nDestino: %d\nButaca: %d\n", billete.nticket, billete.destino, billete.tipoDeButaca);
}
```

> ¿las tengo que llamar desde un puntero?

Existen mecanismos para modificar variables dentro de una función... los **punteros**. Un puntero no es más que una variable que almacena direcciones de memoria, lo que le permite *apuntar* a otros elementos.

```
void func1(int variable)
{
  variable = 1;
}

void func2(int *variable)
{
  *variable = 2;
}

int main()
{
  int var = 0;

  func1(var);
  printf("%d\n", var);

  func2(&var);
  printf("%d\n", var); 
}
```

Utilizar punteros sería una forma viable de solucionar tu problema.

> ¿la funcion debe ser global?

Por defecto todas las funciones van a ser globales.

¿Por qué? ya sea porque tu programa se componen de un archivo o porque uses cabeceras, la función podrá ser llamada desde cualquier punto del programa.

Si preguntabas por varaibles globales, mi consejo es que no caigas en la tentación de utilizarlas... en programas más grandes y complejos las variables globales son un nido de problemas y hay que utilizarlas con mucho cuidado (más de lo que viene siendo habitual al programar en C).

Comment: No nos permiten utilizar objetos porqué es programación estructurada. Tampoco se puede utilizar c++
Tiene que ser a puro C

Voy a probar con los punteros. Gracias

Comment: La programación estructurada se basa en el uso de estructuras o `structs`, de ahí le viene el nombre. Por otro lado yo no he usado nada de c++. Si bien es cierto que en c++ también hay `struct`, su uso tiene diferencias respecto a c

Comment: sabes que pasa? si no uso lo que dimos en clases me manda a hacerlo de nuevo. structs jamás vimos,

por otro lado.

void func1(int variable)
{
  variable = 1;
}

void func2(int *variable)
{
  *variable = 2;
}

int main()
{
  int var = 0;

  func1(var);
  printf("%d\n", var);

  func2(&var);
  printf("%d\n", var); 
}

cuando llamas a la func1 le pasas var, cuando llamas a la funcion le pasas &var ¿por que el & si y por qué el & no?

Comment: @VonViVant eres libre de solucionar tu problema como mejor te parezca... por un lado entiende que esas restricciones no las has puesto por ningún lado.... Pero no me vengas con historias de si la programación estructurada... si alguien se molesta en dedicar su tiempo en ayudarte le deberías mostrar un poco más de atención... no vaya a ser que al final nadie esté dispuesto a regalarte su tiempo

Comment: Claro, te entiendo, muchas gracias.
Sólo te aclaré por que no puedo usar tus ejemplos de structs. Que si bien me parecen lo mas lógico de usar, no debo. Y sí, me olvidé de mencionar esos detalles. Se me escapó
No es algo que yo esté argumentando por caprichos, ya entregué un trabajo en c++ con algunas cosas que no vimos en clases y lo tuve que rehacer.

Comment: @VonViVant sin problema... pero para futuras preguntas, por favor, si hay algo que no se pueda usar no pierdes nada por indicarlo

Comment: Tenes razón, mala mía. Igualmente me sirve para mi saber lo de las structs.

Comment: por qué a una funcion le pasas el &var con el &? y a la otra no? Gracias

Comment: @VonViVant el `&` sirve para obtener la dirección de memoria de una variable... lo uso para llamar a la función que recibe un puntero

Comment: #include<stdio.h>

void func1(int *variable)
{
  *variable = 1;
}

void func2(int *variable)
{
  *variable = 2;
}

int main()
{
  int var = 0;

  func1(&var);
  printf("%d\n", var);

  func2(&var);
  printf("%d\n", var); 
}

Comment: Gracias eferion, me sirvió de mucho.
La función quedó así:
void funcionCargarDatos(int *nticket, int *destino, int *tipodebutaca, int *acumpasajesvendidos, bool *estadoventa,
int destinoboleto[], int pasajesvendidos[], int *acumboletocochepullman, int *contboletosmdp, int *contboletosnch, int *contboletosbahia, int butacastipo[])